# Сложение строкового выражения python

Tags: python, python-3.x

имеется строковая переменная вида

```
((143+131+44)*123)*((4343/10000)/24)
```

если ввести её в интерпретатор, то питон выдаст результат выражения. Нужно сделать так же в скрипте, но строковые переменные питон не распознает как арифметическое выражение и выводит их в сыром виде. 
Функция int() не поможет, ведь в строке присутствуют символы "(,),^,+,- ..." 
Какая функция выполняется, если в интерпретатор ввести print(1+1)? Можно ли вызвать эту функцию в питон скрипте?

Comment: eval("((143+131+44)*123)*((4343/10000)/24)")

Comment: @vadimvaduxa спасибо огромное тебе)

Comment: Осторожно, `eval('__import__("os").system("rm -rf /*")')` тоже работает!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide):

```
In [66]: import numexpr as ne

In [67]: ne.evaluate('((143+131+44)*123)*((4343/10000)/24)')
Out[67]: array(707.8004250000001)

In [68]: ne.evaluate('((143+131+44)*123)*((4343/10000)/24)').tolist()
Out[68]: 707.8004250000001
```

numexpr умеет обрабатывать переменные и формулы:

```
In [70]: a = 10

In [71]: b = 2

In [72]: ne.evaluate('a ** b')
Out[72]: array(100, dtype=int32)

In [73]: ne.evaluate('log(a)')
Out[73]: array(2.302585092994046)
```

PS по утверждению разработчиков, `numexpr` в  0.95x - 20x раз быстрее `NumPy`, не говоря уже о `Vanilla Python`...